# Can you statically compile a cygwin application?

Tags: c, linker, cygwin

Does cygwin allow a statically compiled binary? This would prevent the need for cygwin1.dll being on the PATH of target machines.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nope, it's currently not possible to statically link against cygwin1.dll; if your application does not use unix emulation (i.e. pure win32) you can pass -mno-cygwin to the compiler.

See also the FAQ:
http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin
http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.static-linking

Answer (score 16):

Cygwin's GCC no longer supports `-mno-cygwin`.

Try to use mingw-gcc instead, e.g. `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`, as mentioned in the [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.win32-no-cygwin).

Answer (score 2):

For Cygwin with mingw32 installed, your command line would be of the form

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe main.c -o main.exe
```

This bypasses the need for cygwin1.dll altogether.

Comment: This almost works for me except that I get a "fatal error: sys/dir.h: No such file or directory #include <sys/dir.h> compilation terminated." Any idea what else I need to put on the command line?