# Compiling the same c++ code in Ubuntu(Netbeans) and Windows(Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio-2012, cygwin

I have starded developing a c++ project under ubuntu.
No I want to compile exactly the same code under Windows with Visual Studio 2012(I will add a GUI afterwards for the Windows version) Is this possible? Or should I use Netbeans as well in Windows?

I use the gcc in Linux. To use the same libraries in Windows I must use cygwin right? Do I need cygwin only to compile or also to execute the application?

This is very important, it should be as easy as possible to run my Programm under Linux and Windows!

Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on what you are linking to in windows. If you only link against the libstdc++ probably you can just compile your source code (after some tweaks) directly with MSVC. Otherwise, you either need your dependencies already compiled for windows, or build them from source code (in case it is possible). Using cygwin will allow you to use the gcc toolchain in both environments, but you won't be using VS2012 to compile.

With so little information is hard to tell what you do you really need. Try explaining your project to us.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm developing an application which deals with different time/date formats (Unix-Time, Window OLE-Time, Mac-Time, webkit-Time,...) and also with historical timezone data(using the ICU-Project libraries).

Comment: cygwin in combination with Netbeans/Eclipse would be ok for me. But only if the Users won't need cygwin to execute the program, is that the case?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981043/running-an-application-compiled-in-cygwin-without-having-cygwin-installed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only standard libraries, for sure it will compile in any OS and it's not possible to use GCC on VS, you may install mingw and configure it on Netbeans or codeblocks, or eclipse