# Problem creating an exe from C

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin, exe

I've made a small application in C with Netbeans.
I've ran the application in Netbeans and it created an exe.
I used that exe and it worked fine on my comp but when I move it to other comp it says:
"This application failed to start because cygwin1.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

How can i create the exe so that it runs anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're using Cygwin GCC to compile your code. Cygwin provides a unix-like environment

- if you're not doing anything Unix-y you can recomplie `-mno-cygwin` - see [Can you statically compile a cygwin application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340696/can-you-statically-compile-a-cygwin-application)
- if you are using Unix calls you'll need to distribute cygwin1.dll along with your app
- or you can recompile with a different compiler, e.g. a GCC that targets mingw32 not cygwin, or one of the free (as-in-beer) Microsoft compilers from the platform SDK or Visual Studio Express downloads.