# How to build executable with all library dependencies included for NetBeans?

Tags: java, c++, c, netbeans, executable

I'd like to build my program in NetBeans so that the released executable includes all dependencies required to run it (for example: it needs cygwin1.dll). I am currently not able to run my executable on another machine without having cygwin1.dll inside the same directory. I don't mind if the executable is a large file.

Is there a setting in NetBeans to automatically detect/allow that? Do I need to set/turn on "static"?

Comment: If this is for C or C++, then yes, you need to link statically. (I don't see why Java would have a dependency on cygwin1.dll...)

Comment: just a little warning, I think cygwin is licensed under GPLv3 so that will mean your program will have to comply with GPLv3. but as always with these kind of issues talkt o a laywer. http://cygwin.com/licensing.html

Comment: You could make installer which would extract all needed libraries to the install directory. Take a look on InstallShield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that cygwin1.dll cannot be statically linked.

Reference:
[Can you statically compile a cygwin application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340696/can-you-statically-compile-a-cygwin-application)