# How to Make a Standalone static executable with CLion that can run on anyone's computer for C++?

Tags: c++, static, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

My question is regarding CLion by JetBrains.

I come to understand that with visual studio there is an option to set the executable to be "multithreaded" and not "multithreaded dll". In other words this would allow for the .exe to be used on anyones computer after compiling.

My question is similar but for CLion.

How in the world do I set the same option inside of CLion? At first when not being able to find it I realized I need to edit CMAKE.txt

I also found that I can use the -static option but when I typed in:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

When I put that in it didn't work. What else do I need to do to run a .exe on anyones computer with CLion and how should I go about doing this?

Sorry for not knowing. As a matter of fact I'm new to C++ and just started learning and picked up the C++ Bible to try to learn.

To be honest, I don't see a point in making a program if you can't share it with other people. Even if they installed visual runtime libraries or whatever library they would need it's pretty pointless so that's why I found static is the best way to go.

I just don't know how for CLion.

Thank you.

Comment: (Vanilla) C++ doesn't run on a VM or anything. Executables are built specifically for an OS and architecture.

Comment: Not sure if you know what the question is asking though. An executable can't run on all computers that don't have a visual runtime library installed for visual studio and for CLion it's the same concept.

When opening the executable compiled by CYGWIN on CLion i get an error that says I don't have a CYGWIN dll so i can't open it. I can only debug the file. I can't include the DLL in the file as I was told and that's not an option for me either. I just want to make it use the static operator for CMAKE. How do I do that so that it works?

Comment: To be honest that error is a problem in it's own. It won't open on my computer, not only other peoples. 

But I'd like to make the library my "hello world" file is using static so it will open on someone elses computer. However I'd like to open it on my own computer for starters and it doesn't seem I can even do that.

One day I will be good at coding C++ and I'll need this information.

Comment: So every computer using Windows. Well CMake gives you direct access to the compiler options through `add_compile_options`. That might be a good start.

Comment: Yes every computer using Windows. That's what I meant. Sorry I wasn't specific enough.

I realize if I was making something worthy of Mac OS that would be a completely separate question or research I would have to do.

Right now I'm just concerned with Windows.

I can view the options with your comment however I still don't know what to do to accomplish this.

Regards

Comment: Yeah I actually don't even know how to view the options either. I started learning C++ just yesterday. I'm a web designer and this is new to me. Even if I did view them I'd never figure it out. I'm smart but I just need to know how to make the build static. That's all. I need to know how to make it static so that it will work on any windows computer. Besides I've already viewed the GCC options on their site and found 3 static instances but it does not say the format to put it in and also like I said i the first post the original usage I used did not work.

Comment: Oh I think you meant I should use that format and put the "-static" option in there. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's what I had in mind.

Comment: Yeah tried and compiled. That format didn't work. I looked up how to use it and it failed.

Comment: add_compile_options(<-static>)

That's what I used. Can you provide the correct way?

Comment: Please, provide [mcve]. Currently it is unclear what kind of project you want to make portable. If you question is about statically linking with CYGWIN library, then [it is impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340696/can-you-statically-compile-a-cygwin-application).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

My example is I want to make a .exe portable or allow for redistribution on other windows machines but in CLion. CLion uses CYGWIN for their compiler mostly and that's what I'm using.

I'm new to this so I'm not sure if a library even has anything to do with it. Right now all I can code is a hello world application however I'd like to set it up so other people can open them.

My best example is with visual studios set to static option. This allows it in visual studio so how can I allow the same thing in CLion? That's a perfect example.

Comment: You asked a question, but `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")` was the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much.